Quantile Regression knowing the quantile of X
Many references cover quantile regression either as an expectation value, or over samples, such as
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_regression#Computation_of_estimates_for_regression_parameters
But I have a scenario (using the wikipedia notations)
$$\beta_\tau = \arg\min_{\beta\in\mathbb{R}^k} E(\rho_\tau(Y-X\beta))$$
where I am given the quantiles of each of the covariates $X^{1..k}$, and I can assume that they are independent.
An easy cop-out would be to use the quantiles on the individual covariate to generate "sample"s, perhaps weigh each sample suitably to agree with the quantiles, and then invoke the "sample version"
$$\hat{\beta_\tau} = \arg \min_{\beta \in \mathbb{R}^k}\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\rho_\tau(Y_i-X_i\beta)\right)$$
but I wonder if there are better (more direct) ways?  Thanks much!
